# Find Control In Nested MasterPages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, panel

I have a control in a nested masterPage, that I need to get at in the codebehind. Ive tried various things and havent been able to get a successful result.

The control is a panel called:

```
pnlNewsHeader
```

And this renders on the page as:

```
MainContent_MainContent_ContentBottom_pnlNewsHeader
```

These additional names relate to the names of the ContentPlaceholders used across the nested masterPages.

Here is the structure of the page/masterPages, start from page level up to the final masterPage:

```
 1. BlogPost.aspx
 2. Blogs.master
 3. WebFormsContentCustomBreadcrumbs.master
 4. WebForms.master
 5. Default.master
```

So how the heck do I grab pnlNewsHeader which is located in Blogs.master from the BlogPost.aspx ???

P.s. The additional names prepending the pnlNewsHeader are the names of the ContentPlaceHolders it resides in as a result of the nested masterPages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the master page by calling me.Master:

```
Dim blogsMaster as Blogs = CType(me.Master, Blogs)
```

or in C#:

```
Blogs blogsMaster = (Blogs)this.Master;
```

Then you can just use blogsMaster as you would the page's class (me).

Comment: Sorry, Im none the wiser from your answer. Please expand.

Comment: Did you add the code that I gave to your code? I'll update it with C#.

Comment: Ok, ill give that a try. Thanks. How is Blogs a valid type to cast to? Also, how do i then reference the panel?

Comment: This gives me the following error when trying to build; Cannot convert type 'Site.Areas.Blogs.MasterPages.Blogs' to 'Site.Areas.Blogs.Pages.Blogs'

Comment: It's trying to use the Blogs class from another namespace. You just have to change Blogs to Site.Areas.Blogs.MasterPages.Blogs

Answer (score 0):

add this markup to the top of you page and access your masterpage in code behind. Update the address of you master pages.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Main.master" %>
```

Comment: That doesnt work because its more than 1 level of masterpage.